# How subselect all rows who's index number "greater than" some value in R?

Tags: r, subset

Say I have a dataframe as follows:

```
A<-c(1,2,3,4)
B<-c(5,6,7,8)
C<-c(9,10,11,12)
data<-data.frame(A,B,C)
```

I know that I can subselect just rows 2 and 3 by the following:

```
data[2:3,]
```

My question is: how can I achieve the same by effectively saying "all rows with an index number  *greater than* 1"? (I.e., the row indices for "data" are 1, 2, and 3. So, by requesting row indices ">1", I should get rows 2 and 3 only.)

Comment: You can select everything minus the first row: `data[-1, ]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `nrow` to get the total rows and then use greater than operator.

```
data[1:nrow(data) > 1, ]
```

Also, for example if you need all indices greater than 2:

```
data[-c(1:2), ]
```

Answer (score 1):

`tidyverse` option. This is a bit verbose compared to using base R. To keep the row index, you have to change the row name to a column, `filter`, then change the column with the row name back to the actual row name. `filter` does not preserve row names.

```
library(tidyverse)

data %>%
  rownames_to_column() %>%
  filter(rowname > 1) %>%
  column_to_rownames()
```